# Unable to install FSRM role on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, dism

I tried to install FRSM role but installation failed with error *0x800f0922*.
Tried using GUI or DISM commands

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:FSRM-infrastructure /all
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:FSRM-Management /all
```

finish with the same error.

In *DISM.log*, i can see the error :

```
2022-07-24 11:24:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=77608 TID=77468 Feature NetFx4 with CBS state 7(CbsInstallStateInstalled) being mapped to dism state 7(DISM_INSTALL_STATE_INSTALLED) - CDISMPackageFeature::LogInstallStateMapping
2022-07-24 11:24:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=77608 TID=77468 Feature CoreFileServer with CBS state 7(CbsInstallStateInstalled) being mapped to dism state 7(DISM_INSTALL_STATE_INSTALLED) - CDISMPackageFeature::LogInstallStateMapping
2022-07-24 11:24:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=77608 TID=77468 Initiating Changes on Package with values: 5, 7 - CDISMPackage::Internal_ChangePackageState
2022-07-24 11:24:34, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=77608 TID=77468 CBS session options=0x40100! - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize
2022-07-24 11:24:56, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=77608 TID=76932  Error in operation: (null) (CBS HRESULT=0x800f0922) - CCbsConUIHandler::Error
2022-07-24 11:25:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=77608 TID=77468 Failed finalizing changes. - CDISMPackageManager::Internal_Finalize(hr:0x800f0922)
2022-07-24 11:25:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=77608 TID=77468 Failed processing package changes with session options - CDISMPackageManager::ProcessChangesWithOptions(hr:0x800f0922)
2022-07-24 11:25:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=77608 TID=77468 Failed ProcessChanges. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ProcessFeatureChange(hr:0x800f0922)
2022-07-24 11:25:00, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=77608 TID=77468 Failed while processing command enable-feature. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800f0922)
2022-07-24 11:25:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=77608 TID=77468 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2022-07-24 11:25:00, Error                 DISM   DISM.EXE: DISM Package Manager processed the command line but failed. HRESULT=800F0922
```

In *CBS.log*, i can see the root error *0x8004400a* :

```
2022-07-24 11:24:44, Info                  CSI    000001a9 Begin executing advanced installer phase 32 index 27 (sequence 57)
    Old component: [l:0]''
    New component: [l:155 ml:156]'Microsoft-Windows-FSRM-Service, Culture=neutral, Version=10.0.14393.4169, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=amd64, versionScope=NonSxS'
    Install mode: install
    Smart installer: FALSE
    Installer ID: {9f4ec79f-3a97-4772-b635-2899468900a2}
    Installer name: 'Mof'
2022-07-24 11:24:44, Info                  CSI    000001aa Performing 1 operations as follows:
  (0)  LockComponentPath: flags: 0 comp: {l:16 b:3681d1353f9fd80118010000f421202b} pathid: {l:16 b:3681d1353f9fd80119010000f421202b} path: [l:110]'\SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-fsrm-service_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.4169_none_169374c021471075' pid: 121f4 starttime: 133031282661673720
2022-07-24 11:24:50, Error                 CSI    000001ab@2022/7/24:09:24:50.819 (F) Logged @2022/7/24:09:24:44.226 : [l:50 ml:51]'MOF (install online) $(runtime.wbem)\MSFT_FSRM.mof'
[gle=0x80004005]
2022-07-24 11:24:50, Error                 CSI    000001ac@2022/7/24:09:24:50.819 (F) CMIADAPTER: Inner Error Message from AI HRESULT = 8004400a [Error,Facility=FACILITY_ITF,Code=16394 (0x400a)]
 [
'Analyse du fichier MOF : C:\Windows\system32\wbem\MSFT_FSRM.mof

C:\Windows\system32\wbem\MSFT_FSRM.mof (1)\u00a0: erreur de syntaxe 0X8004400a\u00a0: Jeton inattendu sur l\u2019\u00e9tendue de fichier
```

The file *C:\Windows\system32\wbem\MSFT_FSRM.mof* didn't exist but i think it's ephemeral file copied from WinSXS.

The file *C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-fsrm-service_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.4169_none_169374c021471075\MSFT_FSRM.mof* exists but running mannually the command

```
mofcomp -check C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-fsrm-service_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.4169_none_169374c021471075\MSFT_FSRM.mof
```

return the same error :

```
 (1) : erreur de syntaxe 0X8004400a : Jeton inattendu sur l'étendue de fichier

Le compilateur a renvoyé l'erreur 0x8004400a
```

I'm not confortable with MOF files, some seems are binary compiled, some are human readable.

Note: sfc does not work too.
Note: scandsk reveal no error.